# Dask Client change number of workers mid-session

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have a rather large dataset across different files that I read in using dask, followed by a machine learning task for which I want to use dask as parallel backend.
I've noticed that reading in the files runs much faster using a Client with a higher number of workers instead of one worker with many threads. However, their individual share of memory is then too small to handle the ML task. I would therefore like to change the number of my workers to 1, with the maximum possible number of threads assigned to that new unique worker. Is there a way to do that without completely kiling and restarting my client?

I looked into the [docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/single-distributed.html?highlight=cluster#client) but couldn't find anything of use. Also happy about a hint where to look for this kind of info next time, if not there.

This is an example of what my current code looks like:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as dd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from joblib import parallel_backend

client = Client(n_workers=4, threads_per_worker=2)
df = dd.read_hdf(path_to_file_dir, '/data')
feats = df['feats'].compute()
labels = df['labels'].compute()
dummy = LogisticRegression()
with parallel_backend('dask'):
    dummy.fit(feats, labels)  # FAILS bc of too high memory consumption
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually create Worker/Nanny classes if you want, or use the `SpecCluster` class for more fine-grained control.   These are typically used by developers though, and may not be as user-friendly.